# How to get specific data from nested JSON generated by Google Cloud Vision API

Tags: javascript, json

I am developing a system and trying to get a specific data from JSON that is generated from Google Cloud Vision API and would like to show the keyword on the html. You can see the nested JSON (data) as followed. On the decription, I'd like to show "dog" in my html.

```js
{
  "responses": [
    {
      "labelAnnotations": [
        {
          "mid": "/m/0kpmf",
          "description": "dog breed",
          "score": 0.9408917
        },
        {
          "mid": "/m/0bt9lr",
          "description": "dog",
          "score": 0.91643894
        },
        {
          "mid": "/m/01z5f",
          "description": "dog like mammal",
          "score": 0.86234033
        },
        {
          "mid": "/m/02kysw",
          "description": "spaniel",
          "score": 0.84150785
        },
        {
          "mid": "/m/02xl47d",
          "description": "dog breed group",
          "score": 0.83750784
        },
        {
          "mid": "/m/05mqq3",
          "description": "snout",
          "score": 0.7590523
        },
        {
          "mid": "/m/01p2lr",
          "description": "american cocker spaniel",
          "score": 0.7300941
        },
        {
          "mid": "/m/02wcn0z",
          "description": "russian spaniel",
          "score": 0.6928253
        },
        {
          "mid": "/m/03ht9m",
          "description": "field spaniel",
          "score": 0.6872984
        },
        {
          "mid": "/m/02wbgd",
          "description": "english cocker spaniel",
          "score": 0.65664136
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I write following javascript code but still "undefined" answer for that

> document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = data.responses;

fyi,

> data

is the overall result from JSON (Google vision API).
Really appreciate your big help!!

Comment: You want to show in `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML` every `object.description` that has the word "dog" separated by comma or only the one that match the word "dog"?

Comment: So if you use `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = data;`, does this output the term "[Object]"? Could you show us your AJAX call that you use to retrieve the data?

Comment: @YosvelQuintero big thanks for your response!
however, this json data has so many variety of "description" based on image that i upload in the system. so I would like to get the information of description whatever it is. in other words, it's not only specified on the word "dog" only. So do you have any idea if that's the case?

Comment: @SaschaM78 do you mean this one?

var fd = new FormData($('#cropimg')[0]);
$.ajax({
                            url: 'http://localhost:8080/upload',
                            type: 'POST',
                            data: fd,
                            processData: false,
                            contentType: false,
                            cache: false,
                            success: function (data) {
                                console.log("success");
                                console.log(data);

Comment: @YosvelQuintero oh, I just found how to do it. Many Thanks!!! You helped me a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

To get only one result that match the word "dog" you can use [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

And to get multiple result that contain the word "dog" you can use [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) combined with [String.prototype.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) and [new RegExp(pattern[, flags])](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

```js
const json = {"responses": [{"labelAnnotations": [{"mid": "/m/0kpmf","description": "dog breed","score": 0.9408917},{"mid": "/m/0bt9lr","description": "dog","score": 0.91643894},{"mid": "/m/01z5f","description": "dog like mammal","score": 0.86234033},{"mid": "/m/02kysw","description": "spaniel","score": 0.84150785},{"mid": "/m/02xl47d","description": "dog breed group","score": 0.83750784},{"mid": "/m/05mqq3","description": "snout","score": 0.7590523},{"mid": "/m/01p2lr","description": "american cocker spaniel","score": 0.7300941},{"mid": "/m/02wcn0z","description": "russian spaniel","score": 0.6928253},{"mid": "/m/03ht9m","description": "field spaniel","score": 0.6872984},{"mid": "/m/02wbgd","description": "english cocker spaniel","score": 0.65664136}]}]};

// seachString
const searchString = 'dog';

// one
document.getElementById('oneResult').innerHTML = json
  .responses[0]
  .labelAnnotations
  .find(el => el.description === searchString)
  .description;

// multiple
document.getElementById('multipleResult').innerHTML = json
  .responses[0]
  .labelAnnotations
  .filter(el => el.description.match(new RegExp(searchString, 'i')))
  .map(el => el.description)
  .join(', ');
```

```html
<p><b>One result</b>: <span id="oneResult"></span></p>

<p><b>Multiple results</b>: <span id="multipleResult"></span></p>
```